# Simpler way to selected photo from paper in gimp?

Tags: photo-editing, cropping, gimp

When I scan photos on my printer, sometimes it is a dumb printer and does not take out the background, especially when there is a lot of white. How would I do this on my example photo other than selecting it with the selection tool? autocrop and zealous crop does nothing.
[image]

Comment: All the autocrop operations work for me (there is slight white border remaining), in 2.8 and 2.10. Is the layer properly activated? Is there a lingering selection?

Comment: For me it always says “nothing to drop”

Comment: IIRC it crops until it finds a vertical/horizontal line that isn't the same as the previous one. If you make a 2px-wide rectangle selection along one of the white edges, does the histogram show more than one value?

Comment: Another hypoihesis is that the picture you provided had its contrast enhanced. If so you have a way to autocrop, just do it later in the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the white area using color selection, invert selection, then crop to selection.  If not enough of the border is selected, increase the selection threshold.

You don't have to worry about white areas within the image, such as the fountain, because the crop is rectangular.  However images with white across an entire edge, such as blown out skies, may have to be cropped manually.

You can speed up the selection operations by performing a rough initial crop to decrease the image area the software has to analyze.

Comment: That would probably work except the fountain bleeds a lot of white.

Comment: You don't have to worry about the fountain being selected because the crop is rectangular.